# Reset Timer Interval of Carousel

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I'm using bootstrap's carousel.  You can see the implementation here:
http://jdattorneyatlaw.com/newTimesPost

The problem is that when someone clicks on one of the navigation arrows of the carousel, the interval timer is not reset.  So, if you click back, you might immediately be brought back to the image you were just looking at.

Any instruction on how to fix this would be VERY appreciated.

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: From the code: setInterval calls slide('next') clicking the next button calls this function too. slide() calls cycle() which resets the timer. So i think the timer should reset by default.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to be the case.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Do you use TB2 or TB3. For TB2 you could try to reset to timer on every next / previous click:

```
$.fn.carousel.Constructor.prototype.next = function () {
    if (this.sliding) return
    if (this.interval) clearInterval(this.interval);
    return this.slide('next')
  }

$.fn.carousel.Constructor.prototype.prev = function () {
    if (this.sliding) return
    if (this.interval) clearInterval(this.interval);
    return this.slide('prev')
  }

$('#myCarousel').carousel({interval:2000});
```